# Can't install TTR (tseries) R 3.3.3 (on debian stretch)

Tags: r

I'm unable to install the `tseries` package into R version 3.3.3 (on Debian debian stretch 4.9.0-6) because of its dependence on TTR.  When I run the install, it tries to compile TTR, which leads to the error message

> Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
>  
>     unable to load shared object '/home/moi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/curl/libs/curl.so':
>     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4:
> version `CURL_OPENSSL_4' not found (required by /home/moi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/curl/libs/curl.so)

I did try installing a binary version of TTR using

> install.packages("TTR", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")

But that yield the error message `package ‘TTR’ is not available (for R version 3.3.3)`

The problem appears to be related a request for `CURL_OPEN_SSL_4` from the R library `curl.so`. Since I have `libcurl.so.4` installed, I don't understand what the problem is.

I'd appreciate any thoughts on how to resolve this.

thanks

Comment: Please note that TTR moved from R-Forge to [GitHub](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/TTR) a few years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to (also) maintain `r-cran-ttr` for Debian and here is what I have in my `Build-Depends` in file `debian/control`:

```
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 7.0.0), r-base-dev (>= 3.4.3), cdbs, \
         r-cran-xts (>= 0.10-0), r-cran-zoo, r-cran-curl
```

So it looks like your `r-cran-curl` package needs re-installing.  You may have the `libcurl.so` as a *run-time* dependency (from one or more packages, this is commonly used library) but to compile you need the *built-time* dependency commonly supplied by the matching `-dev` package.

So maybe try installing `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`, *then* install package `curl` from CRAN and once that is there, install TTR from CRAN or R-Forge (which is likely a source install anyway).

Comment: Yes, the lack of libcurl4-openssl-dev was the problem. After installing it, TTL installs with no problem.

Thank you, Dirk